# Warning (char format, different type arg) when compiling my C program

Tags: c, char, stack, warnings, postfix-notation

I haven't learned pointers yet, so I have no idea what other answers were talking about when someone was asking the same question :S...

```
while(1)
{
    /* intializing variables for the while loop */
    temp1 = 0;
    temp2 = 0;
    val = 0;
    for(counter = 0; counter < 256; counter++)
    {
        input[counter] = ' ';
    }

    scanf("%s", &input);                                            /* gets user input */

    if(input[0] == 'p')                                             /* if user inputs p; program pops the first top element of stack and terminates the loop */
    {                                                               /* and the program overall                                                               */
        printf("%d", pop(stack));
        break;
    }
    if(input[0] == '+' || input[0] == '-' || input[0] == '*')       /* if operator is inputted; it pops 2 values and does the arithemetic process */
    {
        if(stackCounter == 1 || stackCounter == 0)                  /* If user tries to process operator when there are no elements in stack, gives error and terminates */
        {
            printf("%s", "Error! : Not enough elements in stack!");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            temp1 = pop(stack);
            temp2 = pop(stack);

            push(stack, arithmetic(temp2, temp1, input[0]));
        }
    }
    else                                                            /* if none of the above, it stores the input value into the stack*/
    {
        val = atoi(input);                                          /* atoi is used to change string to integer */
        push(stack, val);
    }
}
```

it's a program for doing the same operation as postfix with finite a stack. The other functions are all working ok. When I compile and run on Visual Studio, it works fine, but when I run it on linux (which is used to test my program), it doesn't work. It just gives me: "c:52: warning: char format, different type arg (arg 2)".

I am assuming its the scanf or the atoi function that is causing the problem...

Is there any way to fix this program easily by just changing few letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use ampersand (`&`) when reading a character array. Change:  `scanf("%s", &input);` to `scanf("%s", input);`  and all should be fine.

`input` is already a pointer to the begining of the block of memory where the character array will be stored, no need to take its address.

Comment: In addition, it is also possible to write &input[0] meaning "a pointer to the first character in the array". This is equivilent to input on its own, but may help clarify that the scanf is being passed a pointer to write to rather than an instance variable - particularly since the OP is new to the concept of pointers.

Comment: I have added a sentence, please have a look at it.